# Nullable object must have a value. SQL Report Builder

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, azure-sql-reporting

I'm trying to run a dynamic select query through a procedure and I'm able to see the result set while i execute it in the SQL report builder but when i try to generate the report it throws an error. Can anyone please suggest whats the issue is?

[Screen showing the SQL Report Builder with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwQDX.jpg)

Comment: do you checking about null values in your sp result?

Comment: Yes i did check and removed all null values. But no use. Even if there is null the report should generate.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in 2008 and previous versions, which is fixed in 2008 R2 version.

refer:- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0b54621d-e613-4a5e-af13-70b64094e452/ssrs-2005-report-giving-a-nullable-object-must-have-a-value-error-when-deployed-on-sql-2008-report?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: No im using sql server 2014 standard edition. I think problem is with the dynamic query which does not show any columns in SQL report builder.